# In Django Rest Framework, how is the object passed to a class based view from urls.py used?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I've been following the Django Rest Framework tutorial here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/

This code in particular is intriguing:

```py
class SnippetList(APIView):
"""
List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
"""
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I know that the `url` function called in `urls.py` returns a function like entry point to the class based view when using the `as_view` method. Is `request` the object corresponding to this?

If it is, then where does the class access it and its attributes when a `GET` is performed? I cannot see a reference to `request` in the `get`method of `SnippetList`.

If it is not, then what does `request` refer to, and how does the class based view access the data in the client's request?

Comment: `request` corresponds to the client's request and includes all headers, http parameters etc. You might need the `request` variable in your `get` method if you want to do further validation before returning a response, but in this case it's simply ignored. Have a look here for further reading: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/

Comment: DRF is built on top of Django, and these are all basic Django concepts. You should probably do the Django tutorial before anything else.